# Bison IF/ELSE grammar rule

Tags: bison

I'm having problems developing the grammar rule for a if/else....If someone could explain me what am I doing wrong it'd be great

```
/* Terminal symbols */
%token <string> TINTEGER
%token <token> TLBRACE TRBRACE TSEMI TLPAREN TRPAREN 
%token <token> TMAIN TROTATE TFORWARD THUMAN TZOMBIE TATTACK TIF TELSE


/* Statements */

%type <block> main_loop block
%type <statement> statement rotate forward if else attack insideStatement

/* Expressions */
%type <numeric> numeric
%type <boolean> bool


%%

main_loop   : TMAIN TLBRACE block TRBRACE { std::cout << "Main entry point found!" << std::endl; }
;

block       : statement { std::cout << "Single statement" << std::endl; }
            | block  statement {std::cout<<"Multiple statements" <<std::endl;}
;

statement   : rotate TSEMI
            | forward TSEMI
            | if
            | attack TSEMI

;

 if         : TIF TLPAREN bool TRPAREN insideStatement
             | TIF TLPAREN bool TRPAREN else
             | statement
 ;

 else       :TELSE TLBRACE block TRBRACE{std::cout << "Else" << std::endl;} 
 ;

 insideStatement    : TLBRACE block TRBRACE else

 ;
```

It compiles, but I don't really understand how the if/else works on Bison..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These rules:

```
statement : if ;
if : statement ;
```

are circular and make your grammar ambiguous, so you need to get rid of one of them (probably the `if : statement ;` rule.

Your other if rules are equivalent to:

```
if : TIF '(' bool ')' '{' block '}' TELSE '{' block '}'
   | TIF '(' bool ')' TELSE '{' block '}'
   ;
```

that is, you need to always have an else, but you might not have "true" block, which seems backwards.  The `else` and `insideStatement` rules just server to obscure what is going one here.

In general, it's much clearer to use single character tokens for single character tokens rather than making up a name for the token...